# get call passes randomly in karate and passes consistently in postman

Tags: karate

[image]I am trying to call get call. These calls are not passing consistently. Where I am getting proper CXRF token.

GET URL call:

```
Given url appServer +'/integration/live/rest/accessProfile'+'?page=0'+'&pageSize=10'+'&sortBy=name'+'&fieldList=name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id'+'&filter=id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20'+'&getTotalRecordCount=true
```

complete code:

```
Scenario: create Access Profile
Given url appServer +'/integration/live/rest/accessProfile'+'?page=0'+'&pageSize=10'+'&sortBy=name'+'&fieldList=name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id'+'&filter=id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20'+'&getTotalRecordCount=true'
And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = csrfToken
* cookie JSESSIONID = jsessionid

Given request ' '
When method get
Then status 200
And print response
Then match response.platform.message.code contains '0'
Then match response.platform.message.description contains 'Success'


* def accessProfileNames = get response.platform.record[*].name
* print accessProfileNames
Then  match accessProfileNames contains 'TestAccessProfile'


#fetch the access profile id
* def AccessProfileNode = get[0] response.platform.record[?(@.name=='TestAccessProfile')]
* def accessProfileId = AccessProfileNode.id
* print accessProfileId
```

Attached the screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: As the creator of Karate, I'm sorry, you have to create a working example to demonstrate the issue and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - if you claim that it works fine in Postman, just use Postman - or spend the time to help us fix any possible issue.

Comment: Hi Peter,  Issue is reproducible if you use the input param as below 'user_type%20equals%20%27P%27%2' . Can you suggest me some feature file where url holds the params like above. This very mich critical for our automation project. Please have look and suggest some solution.

Comment: if it is so critical - you have to do better to allow me to replicate this problem. I am not able to with whatever info you have provided.

Comment: This issue was related to our application not from karate. Since it was ingix in our application i need to pass route cookie which i missed. Karate is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you have passed all the necessary headers.

Most likely you missed one - for example a cookie that is needed.

Comment: This issue was related to our application not from karate. Since it was ingix in our application i need to pass route cookie which i missed. Karate is working perfectly fine