# How to run junit tests from karate?

Tags: karate

Is possible to run the junit tests from Karate?

As part of our project we need to add junit tests(written by developers) along with karate tests(Written by QA)

Looking for a way to call the junit tests from karate. So that its easy to maintain the Dev and QA tests together.

If answer is yes, please mention the example

Comment: please add an answer (yourself) to this question and mark it as "accepted": https://stackoverflow.com/q/52054509/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call test via Junit.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateStats;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;

@CucumberOptions(features = {"classpath:features"}, tags = {"@sanity"})
public class RunnerTest {
  @Test
  public void testParallel() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/cucumber-html-reports";
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);
    generateReport(karateOutputPath);
    assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
  }

  private static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles =
        FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
  }
}
```

Check @sanity tag should be part of feature file and should be the first line